# Interceptors not intercepting c#, Castle Dynamic proxy

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, castle, aop

I am trying to learn the concepts of Aspect oriented programing and I am using castle projects dynamic proxy for that. Please see a sample code that i wrote.

The interceptor does not seem to intercept ? Or i am not seeing "Inside interceptor, before the call" and "Inside interceptor, after the call" in my console window. Please suggest what am i doing wrong here ?

```
class AOP 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        actual logger = generator.CreateClassProxy<actual>(new proxyforactual());
        logger.add(3, 2);
    }
}

public class proxyforactual : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside interceptor, before the call");

        invocation.Proceed();

        Console.WriteLine("Inside interceptor, after the call");
    }
}


public class actual
{
    public int add(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside method");

        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My bad, after looking closely at the "CreateClassProxy" method signature, i noticed that the proxy will intercept only virtual methods. Changed my code like below and things are now working fine.

Thanks all.

```
public virtual int add(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside method");

        return x + y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use interface and derive your class and proxy from it.